# Pintar cuadrados en situacion aleatoria en el DOM

Tags: javascript

Me gustaria dibujar en el DOM en lugares aleatorios 5 cuadrados, pero solamente se pinta uno y sin embargo, mediante el console.log, veo que se generan las 5 posiciones.
Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
var PosicionHorizontal;
var PosicionVertical;
//var Cuadrado = document.createElement ("div");

function Generador () {
    document.removeChild ()
    for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        var Cuadrado = document.createElement ("div");
        PosicionHorizontal = Math.floor (Math.random () * 865);
        PosicionVertical = Math.floor (Math.random () * 325);
        Cuadrado.style.width = "5px";
        Cuadrado.style.height = "5px";
        Cuadrado.style.background = "blue";
        Cuadrado.style.position = "absolute";
        Cuadrado.style.left = (PosicionHorizontal + "px");
        Cuadrado.style.top = (PosicionVertical + "px");
        console.log ("Horizontal", PosicionHorizontal);
        document.body.appendChild (Cuadrado);
    }
}

function Temporizador () {
    Cronometro = setInterval (Generador, 1000);
}

Temporizador ();
```

Comment: Lo siento, pero no se añadir el codigo de JavaScript.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Por otro lado, tu pregunta no tiene código, te invito también a darle [edit] y agregarlo. No olvides que el código se agrega como texto, no vayas a dejar una imagen del código. Un saludo.

Comment: Puedes usar uno de los botones que resalté en [esta imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0n5C.png) para pegar el texto de tu código dentro de la pregunta. Si no lo logras, pega el texto simple dentro de ella, me dejas una mención con @jachguate y yo edito la pregunta para que tome formato. En el primero, el código debe estar ya en la pregunta, lo seleccionas y le das clic. En el segundo, puedes introducir HTML/CSS/JS para que se ejecute en un sandbox dentro de la propia pregunta. Te aparece un _editor_ al hacer clic. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, he podido añadir el codigo, que antes no podia.  Unicamente falta arriba definir la variable var Cronometro, pero no me lo ha cogido.  Gracias.

Comment: A mi me funciona bien, solo he cambiado `document.removeChild()` por `document.body.innerHTML=""`

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Comenzaré diciendo, solo porque pienso que es muy importante ser correctos en el uso del lenguaje, que en el DOM no puedes *pintar* nada. El DOM es un Modelo  que está en memoria y representa la estructura del documento HTML.

Tu, lo que quieres, es agregar elementos al DOM para que el navegador los *pinte* en la pantalla del dispositivo del usuario.

Dicho esto, pienso que tu código está casi listo para funcionar. En mi navegador, se *pintan* los SEIS (que no 5) cuadrados que genera tu código, cada segundo.

Supongo que en cada ejecución quieres *limpiar* los cuadrados de la iteración anterior, pero para llamar al método `removeChild()` hace falta tener o encontrar referencias a los *cuadrados* a eliminar. En el código siguiente me estoy valiendo del método [`qrySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) para encontrar todos los *divs* y luego, iterando por la lista devuelta, los voy eliminando uno a uno.

La llamada a `removeChild()` sin parámetros lanza una excepción y allí se detiene la ejecución de tu código, probablemente por eso ves solo un cuadrado (que quizás está en tu HTML original o sea la línea que tienes comentada en el javascript que publicas.

Luego, dejo correr tu código, sin modificaciones. Lo dejé en un *snippet*, para que puedas probarlo aquí mismo dándole clic en el botón *Ejecutar* más abajo:

```js
var Cronometro;

function Generador () {
    document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach((element) => {
      document.body.removeChild (element);
    });
    var PosicionHorizontal;
    var PosicionVertical;
    for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        var Cuadrado = document.createElement ("div");
        PosicionHorizontal = Math.floor (Math.random () * 500);
        PosicionVertical = Math.floor (Math.random () * 180);
        Cuadrado.style.width = "5px";
        Cuadrado.style.height = "5px";
        Cuadrado.style.background = "blue";
        Cuadrado.style.position = "absolute";
        Cuadrado.style.left = (PosicionHorizontal + "px");
        Cuadrado.style.top = (PosicionVertical + "px");
        document.body.appendChild (Cuadrado);
    }
}

function Temporizador () {
    Cronometro = setInterval (Generador, 1000);
}

Generador();
Temporizador ();
```

OJO: Cambié las constantes por las que multiplicas para obtener las coordenadas, solo para que los puntos se aprecien dentro de la propia respuesta sin barras de *scroll* e hice otro par de ajustes al código que creo que se auto-explican.

Comment: Muchas gracias, es exactamente lo que queria hacer. Perfecto, muchas gracias de nuevo.